# Possible to write versions in composer.json similar to npm update --save

Tags: json, composer-php, package

Handed a project that has a composer.json that has all package versions listed as "*" and has no `composer.lock` file

In the original project, running `composer show`, tells me all versions of everything installed. Excellent.

Running the project on a different machine, running `composer install` gets all the latest packages, which breaks the project because major updates mess with everything.

I'd love to know if it's possible to trade out all those `"*"`'s with caret version numbers utilising `composer show --save-dev` or something similar. Perhaps only possible by running a script or installing something?

Comment: of course, you can replace the * with the version/tag/commit as described in the doc [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

Comment: Is there a less manual process? 10 projects, all with asterisks etc. Has there been no way to inject the current versions into the composer.json?Even if based on a composer lock?

Comment: i don't know. You should list all the packages under the `vendor` folder by `composer show --installed`. You can use regular expressions to do it easier.

Comment: `composer show --format json` could be your friend

Comment: composer show allows me to see the versions pretty quickly, but it's still a manual copy paste job it seems. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: you can write a script that takes the output of composer show as input and run composer require lib/lib $version for each entry. and then publish the script on github :)

Comment: Make sure to check in `composer.lock` into version control. See https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file.

Comment: Absolutely about the lock file, but that information isn't for me, it's for whoever left this project I'm working on – they've used '*' for all dependancies and deleted the lock file. Now it's a task to backtrack on what versions worked with what. I'd just love to know if there was a way of changing all the wildcards for absolute versions